# SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error - Office Js addin - Internet Explorer

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, office-js, outlook-addin

I am working on office js addin built using reactjs. The addin is working as expected in chrome, and edge browsers, however, when I open it in outlook 2013 and 2016 which they use internet explorer webview to open such addins I get a blank and the following error in the console :

> SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. taskpane.js (134,45357)

App.js

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import { Route, Switch, Redirect, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
    import Progress from "./Progress";
    import AuthContext from "../context/auth-context";
    import Login from "../components/Login/Login";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";

    async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
      let pageName = getUrlParameter("mode");
      console.log("start of UNSAFE_componentWillMount")
    
      this.setState({ pageName: pageName });
      if (this.props.isOfficeInitialized) {
        let _settings = Office.context.roamingSettings;
        let isUserLoggedIn = _settings.get("isUserLoggedIn");
        isUserLoggedIn && isUserLoggedIn != ""
          ? this.setState({ Authenticated: true })
          : this.setState({ Authenticated: false, pageName: "login" });
      }
      console.log("end of UNSAFE_componentWillMount")
    
    }
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log(" start of componentDidUpdate")

if (prevProps.isOfficeInitialized !== this.props.isOfficeInitialized) {
   this.setState({ isOfficeInitialized: true });
 let pageName = getUrlParameter("mode");
  this.setState({ pageName: pageName });
  if (this.props.isOfficeInitialized) {
    console.log("office initialize")
    let _settings = Office.context.roamingSettings;
    let isUserLoggedIn = _settings.get("isUserLoggedIn");
    isUserLoggedIn && isUserLoggedIn != ""
      ? this.setState({ Authenticated: true })
      : this.setState({ Authenticated: false, pageName: "login" });
      console.log("end of office initialize")

  }
}

console.log(" end of componentDidUpdate")

}

switchComponent() {
  console.log("start of switch component")
  switch (this.state.pageName) {
    case "login":
      return ( 
      <Redirect to="/login" /> );
  }
  console.log("end of switchComponent") 

}

 
render() {
  const { title } = this.props;
  //this.setState({ isOfficeInitialized: isOfficeInitialized });
  if (!this.state.isOfficeInitialized) {
    return (
      <Progress
        title={this.state.pageTitle}
        logo="assets/logo-filled.png"
        message="Please sideload your addin to see app body."
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="ms-welcome">
        {/* {<Header title={this.state.pageTitle} clicked={this.loginHandler} isAuth={this.state.isAuthenticated} message="Welcome" />} */}
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{
            isAuthenticated: this.state.Authenticated,
            login: this.loginHandler
          }}
        >
          <div>

            <Switch>
              <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            </Switch>
           
            {this.switchComponents()}
          </div>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Internet Explorer Log

```
start of UNSAFE_componentWillMount

end of UNSAFE_componentWillMount

start of componentDidUpdate

office initialize

end of office initialize

end  of  componentDidUpdate

start of switch component

start of componentDidUpdate

end  of  componentDidUpdate

Error: Unspecified error.
SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.
taskpane.js (134,45357)
```

Taskpane.html

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. -->
<!-- See LICENSE in the project root for license information -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="javascript">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>OTJ Jira for Outlook</title>
    <script>
        var pushStateRef = history.pushState;
        var replaceStateRef = history.replaceState;
      </script>
      <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script>
        history.pushState = pushStateRef;
        history.replaceState = replaceStateRef;
        delete pushStateRef;
        delete replaceStateRef;
      </script>

    <!-- For more information on Fluent UI, visit https://developer.microsoft.com/fluentui#/. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css"/>

    <!-- Template styles -->
    <link href="taskpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="ms-font-m ms-Fabric">
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Taskpane.js

```
if (canUseHistory) {
        globalHistory.replaceState({  //causing the error
          key: key,
          state: state
        }, null, href);

        if (forceRefresh) {
          window.location.replace(href);
        } else {
          var prevIndex = allKeys.indexOf(history.location.key);
          if (prevIndex !== -1) allKeys[prevIndex] = location.key;
          setState({
            action: action,
            location: location
          });
        }
```

Error Log :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFzu2.png)

Comment: Which line of code does the error point to? I think the error might be caused by using syntax and features of ECMAScript 2015 or later, or TypeScript in the code which are not compatible with IE 11. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/support-ie-11) and try to use a transpiler or a polyfill to make your code compatible with IE 11.

Comment: Since you add-in works fine with chrome and edge, Looks like the issue is with some syntax which is not supported in IE11. Can you share which line of code gives you error.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I've updated the post and attached logs error .

Comment: @YuZhou check the error logs

Comment: You need to click into the error line then it will show which line of code generates the error. Then we can see what exact syntax is not compatible with IE. For example, you can click `taskpane.js (188539,7)` in the error log you show.

Comment: @YuZhou I've added taspane.js log, however it is a compiled using webpack and not written by me

Comment: Solved by using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved the issue! You can post the solution into an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter –

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.